# Dropdown bouncing issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I have a Wordpress site where I am trying to add a jQuery menu with sub-menus.

Here's the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.menu > li').hover(function(){
      var position = $(this).position();
      $('.sub-menu', this).css('margin-left', position.left);
      $('.sub-menu', this).slideToggle('slow');
   });
});
```

I have it set up on JSFiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/K96mB/

The problem is that if you hover over a link, the sub-menu slides in and out again and again, creating a "bounce effect". I've been trying to get rid of this, but can't figure out how to.

Also, is it possible to never have two dropdowns open at the same time?

Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this works without bouncing effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.menu > li').mouseenter(function(e){
   var position = $(this).position();
   $('.sub-menu', this).css('margin-left', position.left);
   $('.sub-menu', this).slideToggle('slow')

   });
});
```

I'm using mouseenter instead of hover

Also, is it possible to never have two dropdowns open at the same time?
yes, add this code:

```
$('li').mouseleave(function(e){
    $('.sub-menu').hide()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

To solve the "bouncing" issue:

```
$('.sub-menu', this).stop().slideToggle('slow');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/K96mB/1/

And about your saying that you don't want to two dropdowns open at the same time, it is possible to do but I don't think you want that because the second menu will have to wait for the first one to close then open (lag).

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See **[this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K96mB/3/)** (update of yours).

Relevant parts:

```
 $('.menu > li').mouseenter(function(){
        ....
 });

 $('.sub-menu').mouseleave(function(){
        ....
 });
```